# Two Sessions are created when using SSL as session tracking mode

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, ssl, wildfly

I am using Wildfly 10. For tracking sessions, if I use SSL as the tracking option, I get two different Session IDs for different requests. For example

if /someurl is the requested page, and it has some CSS and JS resources, two different session ids are used when accessing this pages and the resources it accesses. Any successive requests to a page also uses both of these Session IDs.

However, when I use COOKIES as the tracking option, only one Session ID is created for all the requests, which is the ideal case.

```
13:02:33,566 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-14) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:02:33,567 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-14) Requested URL /s/1y1ysP
13:02:33,586 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-15) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:02:33,586 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-15) Requested URL /assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
13:02:33,651 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-27) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:02:33,655 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-27) Requested URL /assets/css/style.css
13:02:33,661 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-29) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:02:33,661 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-29) Requested URL /assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
13:02:33,679 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-32) Session ID - FYH7mlPFHdfJmscyCgCU5-xDyS_8v7y6njuRaB0c
13:02:33,679 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-32) Requested URL /assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
13:02:33,680 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-33) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:02:33,680 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-33) Requested URL /assets/img/logo.png
13:02:46,543 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-40) Session ID - FYH7mlPFHdfJmscyCgCU5-xDyS_8v7y6njuRaB0c
13:02:46,543 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-40) Requested URL /s/1y1ysP
13:02:46,555 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-41) Session ID - FYH7mlPFHdfJmscyCgCU5-xDyS_8v7y6njuRaB0c
13:02:46,555 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-41) Requested URL /assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
13:02:46,573 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-43) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:02:46,573 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-43) Requested URL /assets/css/style.css
13:02:46,579 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-46) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:02:46,580 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-46) Requested URL /assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
13:02:46,601 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-48) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:02:46,604 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-48) Requested URL /assets/img/logo.png
13:02:46,602 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-47) Session ID - FYH7mlPFHdfJmscyCgCU5-xDyS_8v7y6njuRaB0c
13:02:46,605 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-47) Requested URL /assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
13:03:01,563 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-58) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:03:01,563 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-58) Requested URL /s/Xqc2MM
13:03:01,589 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-59) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:03:01,589 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-59) Requested URL /assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
13:03:01,590 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-60) Session ID - FYH7mlPFHdfJmscyCgCU5-xDyS_8v7y6njuRaB0c
13:03:01,590 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-60) Requested URL /assets/css/style.css
13:03:01,637 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-73) Session ID - FYH7mlPFHdfJmscyCgCU5-xDyS_8v7y6njuRaB0c
13:03:01,638 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-73) Requested URL /assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
13:03:01,643 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-72) Session ID - kGcfbG3m8hg8Iuky7rr632g0Lv4sI1bQf8T6xXHY
13:03:01,643 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-72) Requested URL /assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
13:03:01,651 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-75) Session ID - 3sDmYGe2QXmh1AUntFvzrIJqNPLvubDuPxHuciwU
13:03:01,652 INFO  [com.shorturl.filters.UrlRecognitionFilter] (default task-75) Requested URL /assets/img/logo.png
```

The Session ID is supposed to be unique for the requests. Is this some sort of Bug in Widlfly, or am I making some kind of wrong assumption here.

Comment: This is very interesting.  I have been seeing a similar behavior when enabling SSL in WildFly 10, but I have not explicitly set the tracking-mode. I like your filter idea, and will be putting one in place in the morning.